# CGContext and UIImageView Intersection detection

Tags: ios, uiimageview, cgcontext

How can I detect if my drawn line intersects with an UIImageView I drag around?

Somehow the internet isn't very helpful. But thanks in advance!

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 384, 435);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 494, 402);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 537, 419);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 544, 450);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 494, 488);

    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(recting));

    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While dragging you can check the intersection with UIImageView as.
1. `CGRect frame = imageView.frame;`
2. Now if current dragging position is subset of the frame its means there is collision going on.

```
 CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
 if(location.x>=frame.origin.x && location.x<= frame.origin.x+frame.size.width){
//collision with UIImageView
}
```

Comment: but how can I translate the CGContext to a CGRect? I added some code

Answer (score 0):

In your viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear
add pan gesture

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan=[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panned:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:pan];
```

** image panned around**

```
-(void)panned:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panned
{
    CGPoint currentPoint=[panned locationInView:self.imageView];
    CGFloat width=self.imageView.bounds.size.width;
        CGFloat height=self.imageView.bounds.size.height;
    CGRect newRect=CGRectMake(currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y, width, height);
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(newRect, line.frame)) {
        NSLog(@"intersects");


    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"doesnt interesct");
    }


}
```

line.frame is the UIView which draws the line

Hope this helps.

Comment: i just want to find out if it intersects with the drawn line, not the whole view

Comment: isn't the drawn line a UIView object?

Comment: it is but your function checks if it collides with the UIView. I want it to check if it collides with the line